# Download internet file using batch file with rename issue

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a Batch file to download different jpg files from the internet.

The path is in the format: "https:\abc.com\def\ghi.jpg\jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz".

I would like to use a batch file to download the jpg files from the txt file contains several urls of jpg files.

This is an example for file.txt which saves the urls of the jpg files:

```
https:\\abc.com\def\ghi.jpg\jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz
https:\\abc.com\def\ghi2.jpg-orig\jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz
https:\\abc.com\def\ghi3.jpg\jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz
https:\\abc.com\def\ghi4.jpg-orig\jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz
https:\\abc.com\def\ghi5.jpg?jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz
https:\\abc.com\def\ghi6
```

I tried to use the below codings. But it only downloaded the last file. Here is what i tried:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /F %%x in (files.txt) do (
    powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest %%x -Outfile ghi.jpg"
)
echo "Done!"
cls
pause
```

I expect to download the jpg files and renamed as the xxx.jpg (for .jpg-orig also renamed to .jpg) inside the url. Here is what I expect:

```
Download **ghi.jpg** from *https:\\abc.com\def\ghi.jpg\jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz*
Download **ghi2.jpg** from *https:\\abc.com\def\ghi2.jpg-orig\jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz*
Download **ghi3.jpg** from *https:\\abc.com\def\ghi3.jpg\jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz*
Download **ghi4.jpg** from *https:\\abc.com\def\ghi4.jpg-orig\jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz*
Download **ghi5.jpg** from *https:\\abc.com\def\ghi5.jpg\jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz*
Download **ghi6.jpg** from *https:\\abc.com\def\ghi6.jpg\jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz*
```

My idea is:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /F %%x in (files.txt) do (
    **[%%x is the url. AND I NEED TO RETRIEVE THE FILENAME(xxx.jpg) FROM THE URL]**
    powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest %%x -Outfile **[PUT THE RETRIEVED FILE NAME]**"
)
echo "Done!"
cls
pause
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

---

Update(26/11/2023):

Thanks to everyone, here i get my solution, I first generate the output file name and save in LinkAndFileName.txt in the first for-loop. And then I output the file with the second for-loop.

DownloadJPG.bat:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

break>LinkAndFileName.txt
for /f %%a In (Link.txt) do (
    for /f "delims=?" %%b In ("%%a") do (
        echo %%a %%b>>LinkAndFileName.txt
    )
)

for /F "tokens=1,2" %%x in (LinkAndFileName.txt) do (
    echo %%x
    echo %%~ny.jpg
    powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest '%%x' -Outfile 'Output\%%~ny.jpg'"
)

pause
```

LinkAndFileName.txt:

```
https:\\abc.com\def\ghi.jpg\jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz https:\\abc.com\def\ghi.jpg
https:\\abc.com\def\ghi2.jpg-orig\jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz https:\\abc.com\def\ghi2.jpg-orig
https:\\abc.com\def\ghi3.jpg\jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz https:\\abc.com\def\ghi3.jpg
https:\\abc.com\def\ghi4.jpg-orig\jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz https:\\abc.com\def\ghi4.jpg-orig
https:\\abc.com\def\ghi5.jpg?jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz https:\\abc.com\def\ghi5.jpg
https:\\abc.com\def\ghi6 https:\\abc.com\def\ghi6
```

Downloaded JPG list:

```
ghi.jpg from https:\\abc.com\def\ghi.jpg\jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz 
ghi2.jpg from https:\\abc.com\def\ghi2.jpg-orig\jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz
ghi3.jpg from https:\\abc.com\def\ghi3.jpg\jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz
ghi4.jpg from https:\\abc.com\def\ghi4.jpg-orig\jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz
ghi5.jpg from https:\\abc.com\def\ghi5.jpg?jklmno.pqrstuv.wxyz
ghi6.jpg from https:\\abc.com\def\ghi6
```

Comment: Do you mean something like ```@For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%G In ("P:\athTo\files.txt") Do @For %%H In ("%%~pG.") Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "Invoke-WebRequest" '%%G' -OutFile '%%~nxH'"```? Whilst this may achieve your intended task, I'd consider it better for powershell itself to parse the text file. Currently you will be running powershell, which is slow to start, for every line in the file, starting it just once would be for more efficient.

Comment: First, some general advice: Please do not edit solutions into your questions. Instead, post them in the form of an answer, to align with the Q&A format of this site.
If you believe your own answer to be the best solution to your problem, you can [self-accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) it after 48 hours.

Comment: However, your solution doesn't actually work (`delims=?` has no effect). Aside from that, it still tries to call `powershell.exe` _for each and every link_, which is inefficient and slow.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not changing the destination file `ghi.jpg`, the last file downloaded will overwrite all previous file versions.

**[untested]**

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a counter=0
for /F %%x in (files.txt) do (
    set /a counter+=1
    powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest %%x -Outfile ghi!counter!.jpg"
)
echo "Done!"
```

Should solve your problem - except that it should generate `ghi1, ghi2...`

If you really want `ghi` in place of `ghi1`,

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a counter=0
for /F %%x in (files.txt) do (
    set /a counter+=1
    if !counter!==1 (powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest %%x -Outfile ghi.jpg"
    ) else (
     powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest %%x -Outfile ghi!counter!.jpg"
    )
)
echo "Done!"
```

Please don't attempt to apply text effects within code examples - `*` is a significant character.

Comment: Just to mention Magoo, that the saved filename is supposed to be named according to the name of the parent subdirectory of the url itself. My initial comment contains an example which should adequately isolate that name regardless of whether it contans a numeric sequence.

Answer (score 0):

As has been noted in the comments:

- Consider implementing your entire batch file as a PowerShell script. PowerShell has vastly superior capabilities compared to `cmd.exe` (batch files), and not having to mix the distinct syntaxes of these two very different shells simplifies things.
- If switching to PowerShell scripts (`*.ps1` files executed from a PowerShell session) is *not* an option, avoid calling the Windows PowerShell CLI (`powershell.exe`) in a loop, as each invocation is costly in terms of performance.

The following solution makes do with a *single* `powershell.exe` call:

- It makes PowerShell itself read the input file containing the URLs line by line ...
- ... and uses PowerShell's text-parsing operators  to derive the output file name from each URL:

```bash
@echo off
setlocal

powershell -Command "Get-Content file.txt | ForEach { $outFile = ($_ -split '[\\/]')[-2] -replace '-.+$'; Invoke-WebRequest $_ -OutFile $outFile }"

echo Done!
```

See also the following help topics for the PowerShell cmdlets and operators used above:

- [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)
- [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)
- `-split`, the [string splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split)
- `-replace`, the [regular-expression-based string replacement operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator)
- [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest)